# How to save canvas drawing as image?

Tags: android, image-processing, canvas, surfaceview

In my android app i am saving drawing as image.I am able to save the file but its not saving 100% perfectly i.e,some contents are missing spaces are coming. The function is below which is i am calling by onclick. Please Help me how to save perfect drawing
for screen shots visit the following links:
http://www.flickr.com/photos/77093196@N03/7066979339,
http://www.flickr.com/photos/77093196@N03/7066979341

DigitalSignatureActivity.java

```
private DrawingSurface drawingSurface;

    // To save file as Image
        public void saveDrawing(View v) throws IOException {

            File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                    Environment
                            .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                    "MySignatures");
             Bitmap nBitmap = drawingSurface.getBitmap();
            try {
                if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
                    mediaStorageDir.mkdirs();
                }
                String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
                        .format(new Date());
                File mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath()
                        + File.separator + "SIGN_" + timeStamp + ".png");
             FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(mediaFile);

            nBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Signature saved  to " + mediaFile,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not saved",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
```

DrawingSurface.java

```
public class DrawingSurface extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
//some code
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "some contents are missing spaces are coming"? can you post a screen?

Comment: @Waqas pls visit follwing links for screens:http://www.flickr.com/photos/77093196@N03/7066979339,
http://www.flickr.com/photos/77093196@N03/7066979341

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved by setting canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN); in DrawingSurface.java class